# Permission denied: '/home/ugurkaya/.aws/credentials'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

Just installed awscli, and having issues with my configuration.

When I do `aws configure` :

```
AWS Access Key ID [None]: "ACCESS KEY HERE"
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: "SECRET KEY HERE"
Default region name [None]: us-east-1
Default output format [None]: 

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/ugurkaya/.aws/credentials'
```

I also tried `chmod +x /home/ugurkaya/.aws/credentials` but did not help.
Any ideas why am I having this issue?

Edit: `ls -l ~/.aws/credentials` output:

`-rwx--x--x 1 root root 116 jul 13 18:12 /home/ugurkaya/.aws/credentials`

Comment: Start by doing a `chmod 600 /home/ugurkaya/.aws/credentials` - execute permission makes no sense.

Comment: After `chmod 600`, I cannot even run `aws configure`. Gives me this output `bash: /home/ugurkaya/bin/aws: Permission denied`

Comment: Try running `whoami`. It sounds like you aren't actually logged in and running these commands as the `ugurkaya` user.

Comment: Hello @MarkB I think that is correct, the output is `ugurkaya`. But how should I run them? root?

Answer (score 8):

This is due to the **/home/ugurkaya/.aws/credentials** is under root permissions. You can change the permissions of these files to the user that you are using.

Use the following command for this.

```
    sudo chown -R $user:$user /home/ugurkaya/.aws/
```

This will change the permissions of the **/home/ugurkaya/.aws/** folder and the contents of it to the current user that you are running the command. 
Make sure you replace the **$user** if you want to change the permission to another user.

Comment: You should use the following command for this.
```$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/ugurkaya/.aws/```

Comment: Yeah you can use this also

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and found very hard to solve it.
But this issue happening because of permission issue of below files

> /home/username/.aws/credentials
>
> /home/[username]/.aws/config

I solved it by using "root aws configure"

It solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. create a directory by command `mkidr ~/.aws`
2. change ownership of file with `sudo chown -R $user:$user ~/.aws`
3. this command now should work `vi ~/.aws/credentials`